# In ASP.NET, how can I keep login state for two weeks?

Tags: asp.net

I make a website and upload it to a shared hosting.  I use default ASP.NET Login control to login,  but sometimes I have to require login again even if I have checked "Remember me next time".
I hope I can access member webpage during two weeks without login, how can I do that? Thanks!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>

<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
 </asp:Login>

</div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>



<membership>
 <providers>
 <clear/>
 <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
 type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
 connectionStringName="MyConnect"
 enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
 enablePasswordReset="true"
 requiresUniqueEmail="true"
 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10"
 minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
 passwordAttemptWindow="10"
 applicationName="/"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
 />
 </providers>
 </membership>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[FormsAuthenticationTicket Class from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!
If I use "InProc" to persiste Session, what will happen if Session lose in server? Will I be required to login again in client ?

In my mind, I think web server only return invalid webpage if Session lost, because username and password are stored in client cookie, it will return correct webpage when client require the webpage again, and don't require login again.  Is it right?

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="240"/>

Comment: @user check this http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/c3e1fc0b-3ea0-4955-af1e-2c052a55cd23/aspnet-session-how-to-faqs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the forms tag in your web.config you can use the [timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.timeout.aspx) attribute to set the expiry in minutes.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="20160" path="/" slidingExpiration="true">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks! 
If I use ="InProc" to persiste Session, 
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="240"/>

Comment: Session is entirely separate to authentication, and you don't want a long running session at all.